# Php pdo foreach

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Here I have php pdo function to get json from database

```
try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_tabele,naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE prvi=:prvi AND id_akt=:id_akt AND tabela=:tabela");
     $result->execute(array(':prvi' => $_POST['prvi'], ':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':tabela' => $_POST['tabela']));
    $result = $result->fetchAll(); 

          foreach($result as $r) {
          $temp = array();
          $temp[] = array('id' => (int) $r['id_tabele'], 'ime_prezime' => (string) $r['naziv']); 

        }
    $table = $temp;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $jsonTable;
```

but I get just one result, one element in json etc.

```
[{"id":1,"ime_prezime":"Pera Peric"}]
```

other element I can't get. WHY?

I must get json like this:

```
[{"id":1,"ime_prezime":"Pera Peric"},[{"id":2,"ime_prezime":"Laza Lazic"}] ]
```

but I get only 1.st element and other not ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the array inside the `foreach` on each iteration. This essentially means that the array is emptied on each iteration. The array will only contain the values from the last iteration. Move the `$temp = array();` declaration outside the loop to fix this:

```
$temp = array(); // intialize the array

foreach($result as $r) {
    $temp[] = array(
        'id' => (int) $r['id_tabele'], 
        'ime_prezime' => (string) $r['naziv']
    ); 
}
```

The above fix will make your code work, but I recommend using the approach using SQL aliases as shown in [*@YourCommonSense*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22580943/1438393) below.

Comment: This is for me better solution becouse I need different column names and names in json

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a whole lot of useless operations. It's no wonder why you got lost.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

$sql = "SELECT id_tabele id, naziv ime_prezime FROM track_aktivnosti 
        WHERE prvi=? AND id_akt=? AND tabela=?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['prvi'], $_POST['id_akt'], $_POST['tabela']));
echo json_encode($result->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, but it's a good solution. Using SQL alias for naming, prevents an extra loop.

Comment: -.5 doesn't answer the question asked: "*other element I can't get. WHY?*" and another -.5 because we can't give half votes.

Answer (score 0):

declare

```
$temp = array();
```

out side the loop since you have this inside the loop and on each iteration its declared as new array and previous entries are wiped.

i.e.

```
$temp = array();
foreach($result as $r) {

          $temp[] = array('id' => (int) $r['id_tabele'], 'ime_prezime' => (string) $r['naziv']); 

        }
```