# Php PDO array in json

Tags: php, arrays, json

Her I have this code:

```
foreach($dates as $date){

     $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT naziv, vrednost FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND datum = :datum");

     $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => '22', ':datum' => $date['datum']));
     foreach($result as $r) {
        $m = array();
             $m[] = $date['datum'].array('v' => (int) $r['vrednost']);
         $rows1[] =  array('c' => $m);
        }
         $table['rows'] = $rows1;

}
```

And I get: `rows":[{"c":["2013-04-01Array"]},{"c":["2013-04-01Array"]},`

How to show data instead 'Array' in JSON ?

Comment: you would use the `json_encode()` function on the array before echo'ing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580856/php-pdo-foreach and several others

Comment: what do you want your JSON to look like? or what do you expect it to look like?

Comment: "rows":[{"c":[{"v":2013-04-01},{"v":"0"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"0"},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$m[] = $date['datum'].array('v' => (int) $r['vrednost']);
```

This line performs a string concatenation, which implicitly transforms the latter array to a string, which results in the `Array` output.

Probably you mean something more in the line of

```
$m[] = array( $date['datum'], array('v' => (int) $r['vrednost']) );
```

or something similar. To be sure you would have to give us an example of the output you actually want to see, but I think the string concatenation at the given point is wrong in any case.

**Edit**

After your comment, I guess you want this:

```
$rows1 = array();
foreach($dates as $date){

  $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT naziv, vrednost FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND datum = :datum");

  $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => '22', ':datum' => $date['datum']));
  $m = array( array( 'v' => $date['datum'] ) );
  foreach($result as $r) {
    $m[] = array('v' => (int) $r['vrednost']);
  }
  $rows1[] =  array('c' => $m);

  $table['rows'] = $rows1;
}
```

If correct, your ordering was completely off. You want to init a new `$m` for each resultset (== for each date), fill it with the date first, add all data from the database and the push it to your result array.

after your

Comment: hm, no, I need to get this json output: "rows":[{"c":[{"v":2013-04-01},{"v":"0"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"U 0"}, ... ... etc.

Comment: i also try this:  foreach($result as $r) {
  $m = array();
  $m[0]=array('v' => $date['datum']);
         $m[] = array('v' => (int) $r['vrednost']);
      $rows1[] =  array('c' => $m);
        }
   $table['rows'] = $rows1; but not like i want

Comment: hm, now I get this: "rows":[{"c":{"v":"2013-04-01","0":{"v":0},"1":{"v":0},"2":{"v":0},"3":{"v":0},"4":{"v":0}}},{"c":{"v":"2013-09-08","0":{"v":0}}},{"c":{"v":"2014-06-25","0":{"v":0}}}]} not like I want ...

Comment: @gmaestro My mistake. Forgot one `array()`.

Comment: @gmaestro So the last edit did not work out for you? (The one with 2 `array()` calls after `$m` before the inner foreach).

Comment: almost work, but I get 5 'v' => {"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0} and I need to get 7 of this {"v":0} ... ... what is error now?